# Angular $resource: Unknown Provider error, loading dependancies and angular elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Been doing rails for about a year but this is my first real angular app. So far I've been mostly piecing things together from tutorials, but I'm having troubles. I've searched through other SO questions, but I haven't found a scenario like this.

I'm getting the following error when I load the page. I believe it has to do with how I'm requiring modules / injecting dependancies. Any illumination here is greatly appreciated!

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ReleaseProvider <- Release

my main app - mighty.js:

```
var mightyReal = angular.module('mightyReal', ['ngResource']);

mightyReal.factory ('Release', ['Resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/releases/all');
}]);
```

my controller - releaseController.js:

```
angular.module('mightyReal').controller('releaseController', [ '$scope', 'Release', function($scope, Release){
  $scope.releases = Release.query();
}]);
```

my order of loading js scripts - index.erb:

```
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/mighty.js"></script> <!-- main app -->
<script src="js/auth.js"></script>
<script src="js/releaseController.js"></script>
```

and my sinatra API route - index.rb

```
get '/api/releases/all' do
  content_type :json
  Release.all.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change this:

```
mightyReal.factory ('Release', ['Resource', function($resource) {
```

to this:

```
mightyReal.factory ('Release', ['$resource', function($resource) {
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, when I changed the dependency of that factory as above, it didn't affect the error. Still the same, seemingly-opaque unknown provider error.